# Ist folgender Satz richtig geschrieben? Soll ich DER oder AM benutzen?

Tags: word-choice

Wie ist der Satz richtig geschrieben? Soll ich DER oder AM benutzen?

> Bitte finden Sie unten die Fälligkeitsdaten für die folgenden Rechnungen:
>
> 1872 - am 02.02.2020
>
> 1875 - am 06.02.2020

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Geht es um das "der/am" vor dem Datum? Und es sind Rechnungsnummern davor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flüssiges Deutsch wäre m.E.:

> Bitte entnehmen Sie die Fälligkeitsdaten für die offenen Rechnungen dieser Auflistung:
>
> - RNr. 1872: am 02.02.2020
> - RNr. 1875: am 06.02.2020

Die Abkürzung "RNr" für *Rechnungsnummer* ist von mir willkürlich gewählt, bitte hier die Abkürzung einsetzen, die beim Schreiben üblich ist.

Mein Ziel war, dem Stil bzw. der Perspektive der Frage nahezukommen. Denn die Daten liegen in der Zukunft, es ist noch keine Mahnung. Außerdem unterstelle ich, dass es im Schreiben nur um noch offene Rechnungen geht - sind auch abgeschlossene Rechnungen dabei, dann wäre `die Fälligkeitsdaten der jeweiligen Rechnungen` eine Option.

Beispiele für [fällig](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/faellig)(Duden) und [Fälligkeitstag](https://www.dwds.de/wb/F%C3%A4lligkeitstag)(DWDS):

- Duden: a) der Betrag ist, wird am, [bis] zum 1. April fällig
- DWDS: einen Wechsel am Fälligkeitstag einlösen

Die Verwendung von `der`ginge nur bei Umformulierung:

- Für die Rechnung Nr. 1872 ist der 02.02.2020 der Fälligkeitstag
- Für die Rechnung Nr. 1875 ist der 06.02.2020 der Fälligkeitstag

Das ist jedoch (m.E.) sehr unüblich, da hier die Betonung auf "Fälligkeitstag" liegt und nicht auf dem Datum an sich. Dieser Satzbau impliziert eher, als ob der Lebenszyklus einer Rechnung geschildert werden soll - z.B. Erstelldatum, Versanddatum, Empfangsdatum, Fälligkeitsdatum, Bezahldatum...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful!

Comment: @Maria Accepting an answer is not *instead* of upvoting it, you can also upvote an anser you accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Der Text beantwortet die Frage, wann bestimmte Rechnungen **fällig** seien. Und das sind sie je nach Kontext **an** oder **zu** einem bestimmten Datum:

> - Rechnung 1872 ist **am**/ **zum** 02.02.2020 fällig.
> - Rechnung 1875 ist **am**/ **zum** 06.02.2020 fällig.

In Kurzform wäre das also:

> - 1872: **am**/ **zum** 02.02.2020
> - 1875: **am**/ **zum** 06.02.2020

Wenn es nicht um das Fälligkeitsdatum, sondern um das Rechnungsdatum ginge, so wäre **vom** die richtige Präposition:

> - Rechnung 1872 **vom** 02.11.2019 ist am 02.02.2020 fällig.

**Der** oder **den** wäre in keinem der Fälle korrekt.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

*Der* ist definitiv falsch, korrekt wäre im Falle eines Datums *den*. Meines Wissens kann jedoch sowohl *am* als auch *den* genutzt werden, da es jedoch kein vollständiger Satz ist würde ich in diesem Falle *am* bevorzugen:
"Wann ist die Rechnung fällig?" - "Am 02.02.2020"